# What trilogy of Star Trek crossover novels had a monster that fed on fear?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-eu

I used to have a trilogy of Star Trek novels, and I'm hoping that somebody here can remember these.

Here are some of the details that I can remember

- Each novel was in a different universe (first was TOS, second was TNG, and I can't remember the third).
- It involved the Enterprise going to a rip in space in which there were some sort of monsters coming through...their race preyed on fear.

That's about all I remember...my younger self found them to be highly entertaining, and I'm pretty sure they got sold in a garage sale long ago.  I would love it if somebody could puzzle out what this series was called to see if the nostalgia holds up or not.

Comment: “Each novel was in a different universe... first was TOS, second was TNG” — just to be an enormous pedant, TOS and TNG are in the same universe, about a hundred years apart.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/) has a list of [Star Trek novels](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?314), I don't know how complete it is. [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org/) also has a [list of novels](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Category:Novels).

A quick search suggests that one of the books may be [*The Soldiers of Fear*](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Soldiers_of_Fear). It is the second book of four, after [*First Strike*](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/First_Strike) and before [*Time's Enemy*](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Time%27s_Enemy) and [*The Final Fury*](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Final_Fury), in the [*Star Trek: Invasion!*](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Invasion!) series. Quoting [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Invasion!):

> Star Trek: Invasion! was a four-part series of thematic crossover [novels](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Novels) released by [Pocket Books](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pocket_Books). The books spanned all four major Trek television tie-in novel series (at that time), including [TOS](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pocket_TOS), [TNG](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pocket_TNG), [DS9](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pocket_DS9) and [*Voyager*](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pocket_VOY). An [omnibus edition](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Invasion!_(omnibus)) collected all four installments in one volume.

The novels are about the [Furies](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Furies), successively encountered by Kirk, Picard, Sisko and Janeway.

Comment: For novels, [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) may be a better resource.

Comment: That's the one!